# Regex start with + or 00 and not followed by 31

Tags: regex

i'm not to familiar with regex and running into a problem. I'm looking for a rule that:

if a string starts with either a plus (+) or 00 not followed by 31 i get a match

I've been searching and trying for hours now however i can't seem to find the right expression...

I hope someone can help me out!﻿

Comment: Just a guess: `^(?:\+|00)(?!31)`

Comment: can you post some examples

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! For instance it should match:

+44123456789 and
001231456789 but not
+3112345678 and also 003112345678 should not match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?:\+|00)(?!31)\d+$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/23

Comment: You where that quick that the site did not accept my acceptation... Accepted just now ;)